# ZF2: passing redirect url as parameter

Tags: routes, zend-framework2

I am trying to implement "login redirect" for some cases, Like there is a page on my website that is only for logged in users.

As of now  when guest user goes to that page guest is redirected to Login page, i want the user to redirect on same page after Login.

My Login module is: http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/10/23/zend-framework-2-create-login-authentication-using-authenticationservice-with-rememberme/
and have integrated this code in "application/auth" controller.

When i use this url:
www.qa-staging.com/hemaa/auth/login/redirect/http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com
It gives me a 404 error.

when using:
www.qa-staging.com/hemaa/auth/login/redirect/http://google.com  then routing works but i think is not a good practice to achieve this.

controller: auth
action: login
param1: redirect
param2: url to redirect

```
'noModule' => array(  
    'type' => 'Segment',  
        'options' => array(  
            'route'    => '/[:controller][/:action[/:param1[/:param2[/:param3]]]]',  
            'constraints' => array(  
            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',  
            'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',  
            'param1'     => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',  
            'param2'     => '(.)+',  
            'param3'     => '(.)+',  
        ),  
        'defaults' => array(  
            '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',  
            'controller'    => 'Index',  
            'action'        => 'index',  
        ),  
    ),  
),
```

Any idea how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should consider using a GET parameter for that.
Using the ZF2 route parameters for such functionality is not the right way.

So your request will be something like:

```
www.qa-staging.com/hemaa/auth/login?redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com
```

Then in ZF2 you can get the GET redirect parameters like this:

```
$request = $serviceManager->get('Request');
$redirect = $request->getQuery('redirect');
```

And then you can use it later to manage your redirecting for example using the [ZF2 redirect plugin](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#the-redirect-plugin)